# Overwritten "this" variable problem or how to call a member function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, event-handling, prototypejs

I have this class where I am using a combination of jQuery and [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework):

```
var MyClass = Class.create({
    initElements: function(sumEl) {
       this.sumEl = sumEl;
       sumEl.keyup(this.updateSumHandler);
    },

    updateSumHandler: function(event) {
       // Throws error here: "this.updateSum is not a function"
       this.updateSum();
    },

    updateSum: function() {
       // does something here
    }
});
```

How can I call `this.updateSum()` after all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use closures.

```
 initElements: function(sumEl) {
        this.sumEl = sumEl;
        var ref = this;
        sumEl.keyup( function(){ref.updateSumHandler();});
 },
```

Answer (score 4):

Totally untested suggestion:

```
sumEl.keyup(this.updateSumHandler.bind(this));
```

`.bind()` gives back a new function where the first parameter of `bind` is closured for you as the function's `this` context.
It can also closure parameters, check out the [documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind).

To me, `Function.bind()` is the single best function ever written in JavaScript :)

Comment: +1. `Function.bind` will be a standard language feature in a future version of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

DOMEvent handlers are traditionally called with the elements they're registered to as context / "this". This is what jQuery does, too.

The easiest option for you would be to use jQuery's ability to handle event data

```
var MyClass = Class.create({
 initElements: function(sumEl) {
        this.sumEl = sumEl;
        sumEl.bind("keyup", this, this.updateSumHandler);
 },

 updateSumHandler: function(event) {
    // event.data is the initial this

    // call updateSum with correct context
    event.data.updateSum.call(event.data);
 },

 updateSum: function() {
        // does something here
 }
});
```

The other possibility is to use closures to define the updateHandler inside the constructor

```
var MyClass = Class.create({
 initElements: function(sumEl) {
        this.sumEl = sumEl;

        // save this as that so we can access it from the anonymous function
        var that = this;
        sumEl.keyup(function()
        {
           that.updateSum();
        });
 },

 updateSum: function() {
        // does something here
 }
});
```

This is a working example what one of the other answers tried to do. It works because the anonymous function can always access the variables in the surrounding function -- but it only works if the function is really defined in the function that has "that" as local variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is the famous Javascript idiom you need to use in `initElements` function:

```
var that = this;
```

Later in your handler just refer to `that` instead of `this`:

```
var MyClass = Class.create({
    initElements: function(sumEl) {
        this.sumEl = sumEl;
        var that = this;
        sumEl.keyup(this.updateSumHandler);
    },
    updateSumHandler: function(event) {
        that.updateSum();
    },
    updateSum: function() {
        // does something here
    }
});
```

It was covered in great detail in [talk by Stuart Langridge](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/secrets-of-javascript-closures/) on *Javascript closures* at Fronteers 2008 conference.

Comment: No, why? It's a closure so it should be in scope inside updateSumHandler. Didn't test that code, though.