# javascript internal method calls when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with a object that uses jquery. since jquery overwrites the this pointer I cant call my sub methods without resorting to save the this pointer in a that variable is this a preferred way or is there a better solution? Is there a way to save the this pointer in the object ( like a class method with another name ) ?

Trying to learn javascript with javascript the good parts but I dont think I understand all the quirks yet :).

```
//from javscript the good parts
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

var Tester = {
    printData: function (text) {
        console.log(text)
    },
    start: function () {
        var that = this;
        jQuery('id').click(function () {
             that.printData('firstColumn')
    });
  }
};

var test = Object.create(Tester)

test.start()
```

Best Regards Anders Olme
guess this is similiar to [Overwritten "this" variable problem or how to call a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737454/overwritten-this-variable-problem-or-how-to-call-a-member-function)

Comment: Are you using Firefox 4? `Object.create` is very new and is is only supported by FF4 AFAIK.

Comment: No better solution I think - `var that = this` is a classic way of solving issues like that

Comment: i snatched the object create code from javscript the good parts and have it included elsewhere.

Comment: And Im using firefox 4 as well but it has to work in ie 6 too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes, that's what you have to do.

In this specific case, jQuery provides you some help.

```
jQuery('id')   // <-- should be #id ?
    .bind('click', { myThing : this }, function (e) {
        e.data.myThing.printData('firstColumn');
    })
;
```

See the [docs for `bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind). Internally, jQuery is just doing the exact same thing as you're doing there, so it won't make any significant difference in terms of performance, but it might make your code a bit more manageable.

Comment: ok will look into that api. The id is a much more verbose selector in the real code but i guess the example would be better if i changed to #id.