# Using jquery with OO Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to çreate a jquery popup script OO style. I'm doing this because I would like to expand this code with more jquery/javascript  without losing oversight.  The errors I'm receiving are `Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'centerPopup'` and `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-c:`  I'm new to OO javascript, but have quite the experience in OO PHP

```
function popup(){

    var popupStatus = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function()
        {
            this.centerPopup();
            this.loadPopup();
        });

        $("#backgroundPopup").click(function()
        {
            this.disablePopup();
        });

        $(document).keypress(function(e)
        {
            if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1)
            {
                this.disablePopup();
            }
        });

    });

      this.loadPopup = function (){
        if(this.popupStatus==0)
        {
            $("#backgroundPopup").css(
            {
                "opacity": "0.7"
            });
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");

        this.popupStatus = 1;
        }
    }

    this.disablePopup = function (){
        if(this.popupStatus==1)
        {
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
            this.popupStatus = 0;
        }
    }

    this.centerPopup = function (){
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
        var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();

        $("#popupContact").css(
        {
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
            "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
        });

        $("#backgroundPopup").css(
        {
            "height": windowHeight
        });
    }
}

var popup = new popup()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/popup2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Popup!" /></div>
    </center>

    <div id="popupContact">
        <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
    </div>

    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overwritten "this" variable problem or how to call a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737454/overwritten-this-variable-problem-or-how-to-call-a-member-function)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#button").click(function()
        {
            this.centerPopup();
            this.loadPopup();
        });
```

`this` isn't what you actually think. It's not the instance of `popup`, but the DOM element (`#button`). You can fix this by saving a reference on your instance at the beginning of your class:

```
function popup(){
    var self = this;
    this.popupStatus = 0; // you should use `this` here

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function()
        {
            self.centerPopup();
            self.loadPopup();
        });
/* ... snip ... */
```