# Using this(class object) inside click event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, dom-events

I have a click event over a button, I have to pass this class object to call a function inside click event.I requirement is following

```
$(this).on('click', function(){
     this.callFunc();
});
```

For now, I am storing this in self and using it in click function.Currently I am having following code to achieve this.

```
var self = this;
$(this).on('click', function(){
     self.callFunc();
});
```

Is there any way to use directly this inside click function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overwritten "this" variable problem or how to call a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737454/overwritten-this-variable-problem-or-how-to-call-a-member-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context to a callback function

```
$(this).on('click', $.proxy(function(){
    this.callFunc();
}, this));
```

Comment: tnx, this really helped me out fixing my custom confirm... useful even after 4 years. Is there a way to trigger a object's function when the object is about to be overwritten? or to disappear.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind